# Row Level Security Filter in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset, rbac, row-level-security

How can I add RLS on superset in this example

I need to do something like

`WHERE accessgroup = roles` of the current logged in user

I cannot find a macro that does this such as `{current_user_roles}`

How can I do this? is this possible?